# Como montar uma matriz no python com valor indefinido de i e j

Tags: python, matriz, numpy

eu sou iniciante no python e estou com dúvida na montagem de matriz. No caso, eu fiz a seguinte:

```
import numpy as np
n=3
A = np.zeros((n*n,n*n))
j= 2
i = 2
k = i+n*(j-1)
a = -4
L1 = i-1+n*(j-1)
a1 = 1
L2 = i+1+n*(j-1)
a2 = 1
L3 = k-n
a3 = 1
L4 = k+n
a4 = 1
A [k-1, k-1] = a
A [k-1, L1-1] = a1
A [k-1, L2-1] = a2
A [k-1, L3-1] = a3
A [k-1, L4-1] = a4
```

Que resulta em:

```
[[0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0. 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.   0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. 0.  0.  0.  0.   0.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.  1. -4.  1.  0.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0. 0.   0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]
```

Porém o valor de i e j são (são elementos da matriz):

```
 i = 2, n-1
 j = 2, n-1
```

No caso de n=3, foi fácil supor que i e j seriam 2, mas no caso de n com número grande, como eu faria? Eu tentei usando o:

```
for j in range (2, n-1):
        for i in range (2, n-1):
```

Mas nesse caso, dá mensagem de erro avisando que i e j não foram especificados para poder calcular k, L1,L2, L3 e L4. Eu não sei bem ainda como usar os códigos para matriz. (O valor de n sempre será alterado).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Talvez o seu problema seja com o `range`.

Se eu for utilizar `n=3`, `range(2,n-1)` retorna `[]` e ele não passa no loop, deixando `A` sem qualquer alteracão e também não cria `i`,`j`, e demais variáveis criadas dentro do loop.

Usando o código abaixo ele funciona normalmente.

```
n=3
A = np.zeros((n*n,n*n))
for j in range (2, n):
    for i in range (2, n):
       k = i+n*(j-1)
       L1 = i-1+n*(j-1)
       L2 = i+1+n*(j-1)
       L3 = k-n
       L4 = k+n
       a=1
       A [k-1, k-1] = a-5
       A [k-1, L1-1] = a
       A [k-1, L2-1] = a
       A [k-1, L3-1] = a
       A [k-1, L4-1] = a
```

Note que simplifiquei os números atribuídos a `A`. 
Veja que neste caso, `i` e `j` terão seus valores diferentes em cada iteracão para n>3.

Não sei se é isso que queres, mas é o que entendi do seu código.